# Expected Value Notation Question

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Does the red marked box this mean $E[(X-E[X])^2]$ or $E[X-E[X]]^2$?
[image: What does the red mean?]

Answer (score 4):

It means $E[(X-E(X))^2]$.

It is obtained by expanding the square of the sum and we use the formula $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab.$

\begin{align}
E[(X-b)^2] &= E([(X-EX)+(EX-b)]^2)\\
&= E[(X-EX)^2] + (EX-b)^2+2E[(X-EX)(EX-b)]
\end{align}

Comment: It's also often referred to as var(x).